# Oubound HttpWebRequest in ASP.NET still timing out after destination server comes back up

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

We have a ASP.NET web application (MVC3) that makes calls out to another web server using HttpWebRequest.

Anyhow, when the remote server goes down, we start getting timeout errors, which we would expect.

However, then when the remote server comes back up, we continue to get timeout errors.  Refreshing the application pool solves the issue, but we really don't want to have to restart the app pool every time.

Is there pooling that is going on that could be storing the bad timed-out connections?  My expectation would be that if the connection throws an error, it would get disposed, and then we'd get a new connection the next time, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's what our code looks like:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
int timeout = GetTimeout();
request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;

WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null; 

var asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
bool complete = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
if (!complete)
{
    ThrowTimeoutError(url, timeout);
}
using (var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
{
    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseXml = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen/tried the [CloseConnectionGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.closeconnectiongroup%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method of the [ServicePoint class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.aspx)?

From the MSDN documentation:

> Connection groups associate a set of requests with a particular
>   connection or set of connections. This method removes and closes all
>   connections that belong to the specified connection group.

Calling this method may reset your connections without having to restart the pool.

Comment: I did see a few things in the ServicePoint class, but we have not been able to experiment with them.  We have only seen this in production from time to time, and it's a 3 week cycle to push code out there.  I was hoping (probably overly optimistically) that someone would say "yeah, I had that same problem, here's the fix..." :)

Comment: @MikeMooney: I know what you mean, issues like these stink. Yes, the proposed solution is a shot-in-the-dark and you may need to wait weeks to see if it actually "worked"... But I imagine that running `CloseConnectionGroup` in case of timeout or any other I/O failure would be fairly innocuous. I.E. Even if it doesn't solve your problem it shouldn't introduce new issues. :-)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll give that a try.  Hopefully I can come back in a week or two and mark the answer accepted! :)

Comment: Yup, close connection group seems to have solved the issue.  The tricky part was identifying when it needs to be reset.  Obviously not on every connection timeout, because they can happen for lots of reasons and we don't want to nuke every connection in that case.  In the end I wrote a (probably unnecessarily complicated) cache that stored how many timeouts there had been in the last X seconds and recycled the connection group if it crossed some threshold.  this was WAAAAAY too much work for something .NET/IIS should handle automatically.

Comment: @MikeMooney +1 Thanks for the feedback on the solution!